# Path to x86_64 linux kernel headers

Tags: header-file

I want to compile program using some linux kernel headers. But, if I just add `-I/usr/src/linux-headers-4.4.0-36/include` it can't find `linux/export.h`. I saw files with same name in *arch/architecture*, but I can't find `amd64` or `x86_64`. `uname -pmi` said `x86_64 x86_64 x86_64`. What is correct directory in `arch` in my case?

System is `Linux Mint` with kernel `4.4.0.-36` from repository.

UPD: I want to use

```
#include <linux/platform_device.h>
#include <linux/usb/g_hid.h>
```

hello.cpp:

```
#include <linux/platform_device.h>
#include <linux/usb/g_hid.h>

int main ()
{
    return 0; // nothing
}
```

But compiler with `-I /usr/src/linux-headers-4.4.0-36/include -I /usr/src/linux-headers-4.4.0-36/arch/x86/include` said about many redefines and can't find `<generated/timeconst.h>`. I found it in `/usr/src/linux-headers-4.4.0-36-generic/include`. But with same paths in `-generic` directory I also have some errors.

Comment: What distribution are you using?  Are you using your own custom kernel or the distro provided one?

Comment: Some distros have the headers under `/usr/lib/modules/`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Most architectures with 32-bit and 64-bit variants are in the same `arch` subdirectory. This has changed over time; `x64_64` was merged into `x86` in 2.6.24, `sh64` into `sh` in 2.6.25, `sparc64` into `sparc` in 2.6.29. `arm64` is still a separate architecture as of 4.7. `ppc64` moved to `powerpc` in 2.6.14 and `ppc` was finally merged in 2.6.27. `mips64` was merged in the early 2.6 days.

So the amd64 headers are in `arch/x86`.

But you normally compile programs against libc headers, not against kernel headers. (Even if they sometimes have the same name, they have different contents!) Check that you really need kernel headers — that only happens with programs that use unstable interfaces that can change between kernel versions (e.g. some low-level debugging interfaces).

Comment: Good answer, but don't work.

Comment: @val The program you show is not supposed to work: you're trying to compile a userland program with kernel headers. Kernel headers are for compiling modules only.